# Ways to speed up the content assist in Eclipse 3.3

Tags: java, eclipse

From few days content assist has been working very slow and it almost takes 7-10 seconds to assist on any import statement or something. Are there any ways through which I can speed up its action ?

Thanks
-Aj

Comment: Did something about your Eclipse setup or project configuration change a few days ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Eclipse 3.3 ([bug 201718](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=201718)) to 3.6 ([bug 201718](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=289057)), the content assist has always been a bit slow.

The first thing to test is whether or not you see the same issue with the latest Eclipse Indigo 3.7

Comment: Its the same with Eclipse-3.7 Indigo. Even here, the content assist is slow.

Comment: @Ajj: do you launch your Eclipse Indigo with the latest JDK6? And with an optimized eclipse.ini like this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659

Comment: Am using JDK6. And this is how my eclipse.ini looks-- -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize

Comment: @Ajj: right, so try using the `eclipse.ini` I referenced, and see if that make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your content assist is the same thing as code formatting in eclipse.
Eclipse would format your code, organize your import automatically. you can disable the formatting by following this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/309955/disable-formatting-in-eclipse) quoted from Superuser

Comment: Oh ok. Seems to be the reason.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with content assist. The things you describe can happen as a save-action.

Comment: Well it hasn't really increased the pace !! It seems same still

Comment: @Ajj: Can you describe your situation more in detail. So if the code doesn't reformat, the eclipse is still doing some other operations when you save your file?

Comment: I have unchecked the options and now its not formatting. While saving, it doesent take much time, but when I click anything for content assist(like importing a class), it takes 6-10 seconds.